# Portable Vim for Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux-ubuntu

I use Ubuntu as my desktop OS. I want my vim to be portable so that I can use my vim configuration as well as the plugins I use in my college PCs too. Is there any way to have a portable version of Vim for Ubuntu or similar Linux distros?

Answer (score 1):

Save your .vimrc online and download it to each computer you use. Make sure Vim is installed on each one of those computers.

Answer (score 1):

Echoing [tluafed’s answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/14571/10604), one solution is to version control your configuration and clone/symlink it on each machine. Then keeping up-to-date is as easy as pulling changes on each machine.

This is particularly easy using e.g. [github](http://github.com). You can find a number of dotfile repos (including [mine](http://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles)) there. My repo contains vim configuration, a large number of other dotfiles, and an installation script (since I’m doing more than just symlinking things). However, you can browse it to get a basic idea of how to set up a vim config or dotfiles repo, and optionally write a script to do the symlinking for you. This is a fairly common solution.

***Note*** that some plugins may not be compatible with all versions of Vim, so if running more than one version you’ll need a way to disable plugins on a per-machine basis. I use [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) for this, allowing me to simply activate the ones that work.