# How portable is my $HOME/.vim directory?

Tags: vimrc, plugin-system

I'm at home on a few unixy systems, FreeBSD/amd64, Linux/amd64 and Solaris/Sparc. I would like my `~/.vim` directory as portable as possible, ideally in such a way I can keep them identical (say, rsync them after modifying my reference installation).

**How portable is a vim configuration with installed plugins?**

I can think of a few possible issues getting in the way of full portability (defined as *copy all files from your reference and everything just works*). Assume major and minor versions of vim are the same.

- Do plugins install files outside of `~/.vim`, say `/usr/local` or `/opt`?
- Endianness: amd64 is LE, while SparcV9 is BE
- Absolute paths recorded at installation time
- Availability of and `PATH` to third party tools (python 3, ...)
- termcap vs. terminfo
- Anything else I have missed

Before I just do it, is copying everything a dumb idea waiting to fail?
Anything else I should watch out for? I'm happy to have some code in my `.vimrc` conditional on the OS or host I'm on.

**Note**: I know `.vimrc` is pretty portable. That's no what I'm asking. I am specifically interested in the portability of the whole `.vim` directory, where plugins are installed and configured.

Comment: If you put a vimrc file in github repo, you can clone that on any machine and then create a link to it: `ln -s path/to/repo/repo_vimrc ~/.vimrc`. See [here](https://github.com/Matt-A-Bennett/linux_config_files) and [here](https://rafaelc.org/posts/a-way-to-organize-your-bash-aliases-on-multiple-hosts/) for examples.

Comment: For reference we had [several](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14570/portable-vim-for-ubuntu-linux) [other](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/575/sharing-vimrc-options-in-different-computers) [questions](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4027/keeping-personal-vimrc-and-syntax-files-etc-in-source-control) on the same topic. Sharing your dotfiles and especially your `.vim` directory is a very common practice and there are several approaches so I think this question is too vague.

Comment: But basically everything is supposed to be in you `.vim` directory, simply clone it but don't include the plugins (instead use `:PlugInstall` of the equivalent for your plugin manager when you clone your dotfiles). You can also add some tests with [`:h has()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#has%28%29), [`:h filereadable()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#filereadable%28%29) and this kind of helpers commands to customize your vimrc according to the machine you are setting it up on.

Comment: @statox The plugin issue is exactly an item I am worried about. How do I exclude those from copying? So a simple clone of `.vim` is apparently not a good idea.

Comment: @statox The other answers you refer to talk about `.vimrc`, but I am interested in the portability of what's in the `.vim` tree (also in the question title). This is why I asked a new question. It appears this is not yet addressed in any of the other questions.

Comment: @mattb But a `.vimrc` is not the same as the contents of the `.vim` directory tree. Can that be cloned without surprises when it has plugins installed? Or do I need to install plugins on each system, as @statox appears to recommend?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question - I install the plugins on each system. I also have `set backupdir=path/to/dotfile/repo/back_up//` and `set directory=path/to/dotfile/repo/swap//` and `set undodir=path/to/dotfile/repo/undo//` to keep those things synced too.

Comment: Not copying your plugin directory is mostly to avoid having handling git submodules in your dotfiles repository. But plugins are just self contained vimscript code. When you clone them again in a new machine you are not doing much more than simply copying the directories. When you say `.vim` and `.vimrc` are not the same, since vim 7.4 the `.vimrc` is expected to be in the `.vim` directory. So it's still very related. [What I do](https://github.com/statox/dotfiles) is that I simply version my `.vim` directory and add `vim/plugged` and `vim/viminfo` to the `.gitignore` and I never had any issue